# How to display a different WPF DataTemplate for multiple object types

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, datatemplate

The following blog post demonstrates how to dynamically display a different `DataTemplate` depending on which object is displayed in a `ListBox`:

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/different_datatemplates_for_different_types.aspx

Although this is useful, my particular situation is a bit more challenging.

I have a collection of objects in my main viewmodel:

```
public IEnumerableCollection<IGenericObject> CurrentObjects
```

I currently display them in a `ComboBox` using XAML as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentObjects}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, 
                                 Mode=TwoWay, 
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

I would now like to have a separate panel below the `ComboBox` which displays properties for each object.  However, each object has different properties depending on its concrete type.

For example, a `AObject` would not only support `IGenericObject` but `IAObject` as well, so I want to always display properties that are common to all objects and then dynamically display those that are specific whatever object is currently selected.

I don't know how to set up the bindings and obtain the property values for each specific object type given the collection I have makes use of the common `IGenericObject` interface.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> which displays properties for each object.

Keep in mind that binding at the end of the process is just reflection. One can place property names and if the binding fails, nothing is shown.

> However, each object has different properties depending on its concrete type.

Ultimately we are using a converter to hide labels and textblocks depending on the target type contained as the selected item in the combobox.

**Example**

This example is a person and an employee which share the same attributes such as `First`, `Last` and `Phone`, but the employee has an `EmployeeId` unlike the person. We want to show the first and last name for both, but if its an employee also show its Id. Also swap out the headers stating if it is an employee or a person.

Last names in combo, two objects, `Smith` is a person and `Man` is an employee. So when we have a person the screen shows this:

[image]

and when its an employee show this with its ID for the last info:

[image]

**Xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="WPFStack.Views.BindingCoverterPage"
      ... 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Views"
      xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Model"
      xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Converters"
      .>
<Page.Resources>
    <model:People x:Key="people">
        <model:Person First="Joe"
                        Last="Smith"
                        Phone="303-555-5555" />
    </model:People>
    <model:Employees x:Key="employeePeople">
        <model:Employee First="Omega"
                        Last="Man"
                        Phone="303-867-5309"
                        EmployeeId="90125" />
    </model:Employees>
    <converter:EmployeeVisiblity x:Key="isEmployeeVisibility"/>
    <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-20,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ComboBox Name="mySelectionCombo"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                DisplayMemberPath="Last"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                Width="200">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource people}}" />
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeePeople}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>

    <StackPanel Margin="10">

        <Label Content="Employee Stats:"
                Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                            ElementName=mySelectionCombo,
                            Converter={StaticResource isEmployeeVisibility}}" />

        <Label Content="Person Stats:"
                Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                            ElementName=mySelectionCombo,
                            ConverterParameter=Reverse,
                            Converter={StaticResource isEmployeeVisibility}}" />

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.First, ElementName=mySelectionCombo}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Last, ElementName=mySelectionCombo}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EmployeeId, ElementName=mySelectionCombo}"
                    Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                            ElementName=mySelectionCombo,
                            Converter={StaticResource isEmployeeVisibility}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**Converter**

```
namespace WPFStack.Converters
{
public class EmployeeVisiblity : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (value != null)
            if (value is Employee)
            {
                if (parameter == null) // Does not say string "Reverse"
                    isVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        else // Value is a person
            {
                if (parameter != null) // Does say string "Reverse"
                    isVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            }

        return isVisible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
}
```

---

**Usage**

Note that what the example is primarily doing is simply binding to a *similar* (but not the same type of things as your data) for **it is process and not the data one needs to focus on** for the answer to the question.

Even though I am using a Composite Collection to hold  set of data such as yours via `ItemsSource`, I end up (like you) with a list of different *instance* objects, just like your data.

So....

Focus on that point on and see how the converter works to determine what to make visible and what not depending on what the combobox has selected.

Here are the following steps which you will need to implement and understand to make it work in your code:

1. Make a converter like the one in your project. Note the namespace.
2. Make a xaml import reference and name it converter. My namespace was `WPFStack.Converters` so bringing it into Xaml made mine `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Converters"`.
3. Create a static instance in Xaml of the converter you created by specifying it in the page resources `<converter:EmployeeVisiblity x:Key="isEmployeeVisibility"/>`.
4. Any visual control on the screen you need to hide, on its `Visbility` property will bind to the current selected item of the combo (which you may need to provide a name for the binding) and also call your converter to determine if it is shown or not such as this xaml code:

   `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EmployeeId, ElementName=mySelectionCombo}"
                       Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                               ElementName=mySelectionCombo,
                               Converter={StaticResource isEmployeeVisibility}}" />`

That is the takeaway you need to have from this response.

Comment: What is WPFStack and where do I find it?

Comment: @gonzobrains WPF stack is a WPF Visual Studio scratch project built from the WPF wizard in visual studio. You can build one by my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) which shows the basics of MVVM. See my update on more of an explanation of how to use this example.